# How to abort a cherry-pick?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I ran `git cherry-pick <hash>` and had merge conflicts. I don't want to resolve the conflicts, I just want to abort the cherry-pick. When doing an actual merge (with `git merge`) there's the handy `git merge --abort`. What's the equivalent of cherry-picking?

Answer (score 931, accepted):

You can do the following

```
git cherry-pick --abort
```

From the [`git cherry-pick` docs](http://jk.gs/git-cherry-pick.html)

> ```
> --abort
> ```
>
> Cancel the operation and return to the pre-sequence state.

Comment: Has the --abort option been removed/added in a specific git version? I'm running git 1.7.4.1 and "git cherry-pick --abort" results in a git cherry-pick usage message. I also grepped "git help cherry-pick" for "abort" and didn't find anything.

Comment: @danns87 the `--abort` option became available at [version 1.7.8](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.4.2/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt#L31-32). Is it possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: yes, this doesn't work. Most of the times I get this `error: Entry '<unstaged file>' not uptodate. Cannot merge.`

On the other hand, `git reset --merge` does work!

Comment: @KumarHarsh which version of Git are you using?

Comment: >1.8. Actually, it was because of dirty files in the directory. But the `git reset --merge` command works even then.

Comment: The --abort option always worked for me until today, when it started a memory leak somehow.  I watched my memory usage increase linearly to just short of maximum when the --abort command errored out with a calloc error.  Trying variations on "git reset" produced the same result.  Stuck, I found the only way to resolve the issue was to a̶d̶d̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶m̶e̶m̶o̶r̶y̶ undo all changes made by the cherry-pick, and then attempt to abort it.

Comment: Is it possible to abort the cherry-pick, but keep the changes? I decided I want to amend the previous commit with the cherry-picked changes instead.

Comment: rror: Entry 'TimeFountain/Extensions/String+matrix.swift' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'a6f60f1752e46f91259d93ec78b13dc836bff81f'.
fatal: cherry-pick failed

Answer (score 101):

I found the answer is `git reset --merge` - it clears the conflicted cherry-pick attempt.

Comment: Is it any different from `git reset --hard`? I'm using rebase workflow, if anything. It seems to work out for me.

Comment: what's the difference between `--merge` and `--abort`?

Answer (score 25):

For me, the only way to reset the failed cherry-pick-attempt was

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and only suggests an operation likely to destroy data.

Comment: If your cherry-pick succeeded and you actually just want to revert the changes made by it, then this is the right answer, but be warned that it will lose any other changes you've made, not just ones due to the cherry-pick.

Answer (score 12):

Try also with '--quit' option, which allows you to abort the current operation and **further** clear the sequencer state.

> --quit
>     Forget about the current operation in progress. Can be used to clear the sequencer state after a failed cherry-pick or revert.
>
> --abort
>     Cancel the operation and return to the pre-sequence state.

use help to see the original doc with more details, 
$ git help cherry-pick

I would avoid 'git reset --hard HEAD' that is too harsh and you might ended up doing some manual work.

Comment: That shouldn't exist. Git is complicated enough without two ways of canceling a cherry pick that have subtly different effects on the repo state.

Comment: True, it doesn't give me any error, but not not completely quitting the command state.